# (MySQL) Why are there no rows showing after a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a quick question about why rows are not showing up after a query. Here's a sample query I'm using based on 3 tables I have in my database.

```
    select ff9characters.name, ff9apchart.apneeded 
    from ff9characters 
    join ff9apchart 
    on ff9apchart.charID=ff9characters.id
    join ff9abilities
    on ff9apchart.abilityid=ff9abilities.id
    where ff9abilities.ability = 'Accuracy+'
    group by ff9characters.name
    order by ff9characters.id;
```

Nothing shows up at all. I would like to add that the ability column in ff9abilities is filled with data of the text datatype and has 'Accuracy+' listed.

If I change the WHERE statement to:

```
where ff9abilities.ability like 'Acc%'
```

All of the data shows up. I got 4 rows returned (which was my desired result).

Should I have changed the datatype for the ability column from text to varchar instead so that it reads all the data?

Comment: Are you certain there are no additional characters after `Accuracy+` in your data?  (e.g.: `Accuracy+    `)

Comment: Ahhh, that's a good point. I need to take a look at the txt file as the information was imported via the "load data local infile" command. Formatting must have been off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be you have improper white space  try with trim and (lower)

```
  select ff9characters.name, ff9apchart.apneeded 
  from ff9characters 
  join ff9apchart 
  on ff9apchart.charID=ff9characters.id
  join ff9abilities
  on ff9apchart.abilityid=ff9abilities.id
  where trim(ff9abilities.ability) = 'Accuracy+'
  group by ff9characters.name
  order by ff9characters.id;
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I think I discovered my problem - the data in each cell had extra characters (in the form of blanks) after the words.